# Adding a sqlite3 trigger in Ruby on rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have these two migrations:

```
class CreateBreakdowns < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :breakdowns do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :content
      t.decimal :amount
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateDailyTotals < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
    create_table :daily_totals do |t|
      t.date      :date
      t.decimal   :total
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And, I want to add below trigger to the migration:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_total AFTER INSERT ON breakdowns
    BEGIN
      UPDATE daily_totals
      SET total = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM breakdowns WHERE New.date = date)
      WHERE New.date = date;
    END;
```

The purpose is when the user inserts a data into the breakdowns table, then execute a trigger to update the daily_totals.

My question is which migration file do I have to add this trigger? And, will it just work if I add this trigger into the migration file?

I tried the trigger with my testing db and it works, it's just not working with the rails. Again, I'm using sqlite3, not mySQL or Oracle SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: I got to ask, way not do this in plain ruby ? If you are using rails that's easier to implement and can improve performance when done right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute raw SQL inside your migration:

```
class CreateUpdateTotalTrigger < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE TRIGGER update_total AFTER INSERT ON breakdowns
      BEGIN
        UPDATE daily_totals
        SET total = (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM breakdowns WHERE New.date = date)
        WHERE New.date = date;
      END;
    SQL
  end
end
```

I had a similar use case for procedures in PostgreSQL which are not supported.

I have created a stored procedure concern:

```
# app/procedures/concerns/stored_procedure.rb
module StoredProcedure
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    self.abstract_class = true
  end

  module ClassMethods
    # without return value
    def execute_sp(sql, *bindings)
      perform_sp(:execute, sql, *bindings)
    end

    # select many return values
    def fetch_sp(sql, *bindings)
      perform_sp(:select_all, sql, *bindings)
    end

    # select single return value
    def fetch_sp_val(sql, *bindings)
      perform_sp(:select_value, sql, *bindings)
    end

    protected

    def perform_sp(method, sql, *bindings)
      sql = send(:sanitize_sql_array, bindings.unshift(sql)) if bindings.any?
      connection.send(method, sql)
    end
  end
end
```

Then I created an ActiveRecord class for stored procedures:

```
# app/procedures/sp_active_record.rb
class SpActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  class << self
    def drop_function(function_name, *types)
      connection.execute("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS #{function_name}(#{types ? types.join(', ') : nil});")
    end

    def create_function
      connection.execute(minify("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION #{yield};"))
    end

    private

    def minify(string)
      string.tr("\n", ' ').gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
    end
  end
end
```

Finally I create a class for each procedure:

```
class SpYoutubeChannel < SpActiveRecord
  include StoredProcedure
  class << self
    def show_interactions_by(interval, start_date = nil, end_date = nil)
      fetch_sp(minify(interactions_statement), interval, start_date, end_date).map { |r| OpenStruct.new(r) }
    end

    def interactions_statement
      <<-SQL
      ----
      SQL
    end
  end
end
```

And I can use my helpers in the migration

```
class CreateYoutubeInteractionsF < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    SpActiveRecord.drop_function(:youtube_interactions_f, 'int', 'date', 'date')
    SpActiveRecord.create_function do
      <<-SQL
      youtube_interactions_f(
        interval_size int, start_period date, end_period date
      )
      ---
      SQL
    end
  end

  def down
    SpActiveRecord.drop_function(:youtube_interactions_f, 'int', 'date', 'date')
  end
end
```

You can definitely do the same thing for Triggers!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, I have to create a separate migration only for the trigger? Can't I just add the trigger code inside of the daily_totals migration?

Comment: I would say yes (with `def up; end` for creating and `def down; end` for dropping it). If you use several triggers, you might want to create a complex architecture as I did  for procedures

Comment: did this answer to your question?

Comment: Definitely! I didn't have a chance to try the code yet, but I get the idea. Thanks a bunch!